# How load SVG from BaseHTTPServer in python?

Tags: python, svg, httpserver

I created a server with python.

Now I have a webpagecgi to screen my result and also a svg file.
I tested 3 ways to that:
Solution1 a javascript method to load quicky the svg (works out of server-> but not in the localserver)
Solution2 a simple object import (works out of server -> but not in the localserver) 
Solution3 svg inside the html (works out and in the server)

I would like to use the solution 1 or 2 because the 3 is not comfortable and dirty for me...
Why Solution1 and 2 does not work? I think they do not find svg file but I don't understand why...

```
    os.system("cp %s WEBSERVER/toto.svg"%(svg))
    print 'Content-type: text/html' #application/xhtml+xml'# image/svg+xml'
    print '''    
    <html>
    <head>
    <script language="javascript">
    function loadSVG(id, svg) {
            var element = document.getElementById(id);
            var object = document.createElement("object");
            object.type = "image/svg+xml";
            object.data = svg;
            element.appendChild(object);
            }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>


        SOLUTION1<br/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            loadSVG('hca', 'WEBSERVER/toto.svg');
        </script>

        SOLUTION2<br/>
        <object type='image/svg+xml' data ='WEBSERVER/toto.svg'></object>

        SOLUTIONT3<br/>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width="800" height="800" >
            <rect x="50" y="200" width="250" height="40" />
        </svg>
    </body>

</html>
    '''
```

Here is the webserver that I launch in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import BaseHTTPServer
import CGIHTTPServer
import cgitb; cgitb.enable() 

server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("0.0.0.0", 8123)
handler.cgi_directories = ['/WEBSERVER']

httpd = server(server_address, handler)

try:    
    print "Running HTTP server"
    httpd.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Server Stoped"
```

Comment: If I understand well, you want to display a SVG file in a browser, that file being on your server ? solution 2 seems the simplest and the best. If it doesn't work, it's probably that your svg file is not accessible by your server. try to get it directly in your browser, typing the URL in your URL bar. One issue may be permission settings on this file

Comment: I don't know if it is accessible or not, normally yes because is 777. when I write in the URL bar I obtain that:
Error response

Error code 403.

Message: CGI script is not executable ('/WEBSERVER/toto.svg').

Error code explanation: 403 = Request forbidden -- authorization will not help.

Comment: so basically your problem is serving static file with your server. how did you implement your server ? you should find how to do it with the doc of the library you used (try to look at "how to serve static files")

Comment: I add my python server in the initial message. I search on the web but I really do not understand. I can execute program through my cgi script but I can't import image or object because it does not see it... strange isn't it?